# How to fix showing a previous version of an Vue app when you open the app for the first time?

Tags: vue.js, caching, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Vue app. When I make a new release and open it in the browser for the first time, it shows the previous version of the app. Then I refresh the page (**WITHOUT CLEARING THE CACHE**), just press F5 and it shows the correct version of the app.

We use .gitlab-ci.yml to build the application release. Maybe our problem is related to this file?

```
image: node:14-alpine

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

Build_JS_dev:
  stage: build
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - .yarn/
  tags:
    - web
  before_script:
    - apk update && apk add yarn
    - yarn install
    - yarn config set cache-folder .yarn
    - echo "$ENV_DEV" > .env
  script:
    - yarn build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/
    expire_in: 1 week
  only:
    - dev

Build_JS_demo:
  stage: build
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - .yarn/
  tags:
    - web
  before_script:
    - apk update && apk add yarn
    - yarn install
    - yarn config set cache-folder .yarn
    - echo "$ENV_DEMO" > .env
  script:
    - yarn build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/
    expire_in: 1 week
  only:
    - test

Build_JS_prod:
  stage: build
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - .yarn/
  tags:
    - web
  before_script:
    - apk update && apk add yarn
    - yarn install
    - yarn config set cache-folder .yarn
    - echo "$ENV_PROD" > .env
  script:
    - yarn build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/
    expire_in: 1 week
  only:
    - master

Deploy_dev:
  stage: deploy
  image: kroniak/ssh-client
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  script:
    - scp -r dist/ ubuntu@dev-split.daichicloud.ru:/home/ubuntu/php-core/app/webfront/
  only:
    - dev

Deploy_demo:
  stage: deploy
  image: kroniak/ssh-client
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  script:
    - scp -r dist/ ubuntu@demo-split.daichicloud.ru:/home/ubuntu/php-core/app/webfront/
  only:
    - test

Deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  image: kroniak/ssh-client
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  script:
    - scp -r dist/ ubuntu@split.daichicloud.ru:/home/ubuntu/app/app/webfront/
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
```

For a better understanding, here are the problem steps:

1. I push a new release to the master branch on gitlab.
2. gitlab-ci make an artifact in the dist folder.
3. The dist folder is then sent to the application server. After that, the application update is DONE.
4. I open the app in a new tab in the Chrome browser. I see an OLD version of the application.
5. I press the F5 key (NOT ctrl + F5, without clearing the cache). The application version changes to the correct one.
6. Again I open the app in a new tab in the Chrome browser. And again I see an OLD version of the application.
7. Again I press the F5 key (NOT ctrl + F5, without clearing the cache). The application version changes to the correct one.
   And so on.....

In another post, I saw the advice to change the version of the application in the package.json file. But it did not help

```
{
  "name": "daichi",
  "version": "1.3.1.1",
  "private": true,
```

I have no idea how to fix it. I would appreciate any advice